# How do I change my ubuntu keepalive to infinity?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keepalive

http://www.golinuxhub.com/2013/03/setting-up-custom-tcpip-keep-alive.html

Once I connect to my development server, I don't want it to automatically disconnect unless I quit my terminal.

What settings should I use?

Comment: Connect via what?

Comment: A more reliable Internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

So here are two fixes. The first is server side.

1. ssh to your server, and as root or sudo edit the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config then add the line:

   > **ClientAliveInterval 60**

   This will send a timeout signal to the client every 60 seconds. The client (your desktop/laptop) is expected to be alive and answer. If it does, all is well. If not, the signals will continue every 60 seconds until a maximum count is reached (default is 3). Then the server will disconnect. So: if your client is connected and live, even if it is idle, this line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config will ensure no timeout happens. 
   The maximum count can be set with:

   > **ClientAliveCountMax 3**

   (default is 3). But you don’t really need to do that. You will now need to restart your ssh server:

   **sudo service ssh restart**
2. Alternatively, on the client side (your own desktop/laptop) edit the /etc/ssh/ssh_config (again, as root or sudo) and add the following line:

   > **ServerAliveInterval 60**

   This is good for when you either don’t have root on your server, or you just don’t want to mess around with configuration files on the server itself.